# How should I find the shortest path in the graph using linked list

Tags: algorithm, graph, linked-list, pseudocode

There are n nodes and there are edges between the nodes if they are connected directly.
Each edge does not have weight and direction (If node a and b are connected, it means connected both way not one way).

Based on the graph, we can draw adjacency matrix which is two-dimensional array, A[0][0]...A[n-1][n-1]. So, the question is how to return the shortest path. If there is no path, should return empty path. And the path should return using linked list.

```
 |A B C D E
A|0 1 0 1 0
B|1 0 1 0 0 
C|0 1 0 1 0
D|1 0 1 0 1
E|0 0 0 1 0
```

So, based on the Matrix above, the shortest path from C to E is [C,D,E]. And the shortest path from A to C is [A,B,C].

We should use pseudo code with O(n^2) time complexity. And I briefly guess BFS approach would be great.

Comment: A tree always has one path between two nodes. That is actually the definition of a tree: A tree is a graph where every two vertices are connected by exactly one path. So the "shortest" path in a tree does not make much sense.

Comment: @Will You're right. I've just deleted tree hash tag

Comment: To find a shortest path between two nodes in an unweighted graph you can use BFS, there're plenty pseudo code example on the internet even on Wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](http://www.gitta.info/Accessibiliti/en/html/Dijkstra_learningObject1.html) article answers your question. This problem can be solved with Dijkstra's algorithm. In your case the weight of each edge is equal to 1 so just make the `dist_between(u,v) = 1` in the pseudo code. Time complexity of the solution is O(V^2). Note that,
 `previous[v]`= *the node previous to the vth node in the shortest path to node v from the starting node*. 
That means, in order to visit the vth node in the shortest possible way, you have to first come to the `previous [v]` node. So using this `previous` array, you can return the shortest path in any way you desire. If there is no path, the  `dist[v]` in the pseudo code will be infinity.

Comment: Exactly! Thx for your answer.